# Node JS web service based on api key

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, api-key

I have some web services, written in node js and express. I want to use api key based service.
Suppose I currently have a web service "getRooms".

```
app.get('/getRooms/', function (req, res) {
    'use strict';
    N.API.getRooms(function (rooms) {
        res.send(rooms);
    },function (err) {
        res.send(err);
    });
});
```

I am using it by calling https://xxxxxx/getRooms.
Now I want to use https://xxxxxx/APIKEY/getRooms. This APIKEY is different for different clients. So how do I modify my web services to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify it as `/APIKEY/getrooms` to achieve the desired result. However it would be better it you send `APIKEY` in request header but obviously it depends on your case.

Comment: can you please explain what is route at /xxxxx. so that I can post

Comment: I have edited the answer check. you simply have to put APIKEY before /getrooms/

Comment: api keys will be different, which are _id from mongodb. then how do I define APIKEY statically

Comment: you can use a param then /:apikey/getrooms. So the request will be like :

       `/c822c1b63853ed273b89687ac505f9fa/getrooms. `
       `/123456789/getrooms.`

      `/getrooms will result in 404.`

Comment: Yes this is what I wanted. let me try first. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can modify your code like this

```
app.get('/getRooms?api_key=xxxx', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.query.api_key) // print xxxx when user request to https://xxxxxx/getRooms/APIKEY
});
```

Comment: I've thought of this procedure, but if I already have a parameter for that web service? like
app.get('/getRoom/:room', function (req, res) {})

Comment: so you need setup to user send request with api_key in headers. Then in server side you can get user api key with req.headers['api_key']

Comment: Putting in header is a good approach when it will be called from code. For GET services, if we hit it in URL, then header part won't work.